# Top-level menu item to edit a specific page

Tags: wordpress

I'm not sure if this is possible or advisable, but I'd like to have a top-level menu item on the sidebar in the admin dashboard that links to a specific page within wordpress for editing.

Maybe there's a better way of doing this... here's the functionality I'm after:

I have a page called "Upgrade Contents" where my client can edit the contents of their upgrade package sitewide. I'd like them to be able to edit this page directly from the admin dashboard, like a setting page. Problem is, I don't know how to add a link to edit this page to the admin AND I already have everything set up with ACF using this page.

Is adding a link easy to do or should I just scrap it and make a settings page for my theme and add THAT to the admin?

Answer (score 0):

To add a link at the top level of the menu you can add an item to the global `$menu` array, like this:

```
function link_to_user_settings() {
    global $menu;

    $title      = 'User Settings';
    $url        = 'URL_OF_YOUR_PAGE';
    $position   = 73;
    $permission = 'read';
    $icon       = 'dashicons-admin-links';

    $menu[$position] = array( $title, $permission, $url, '', 'menu-top', '', $icon );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'link_to_user_settings' );
```

Change the variables accordingly to your needs.

The `$position` var is where you want the link to appear based on the default positions you can find at the [`add_menu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) documentation (in my example `73` means after the `Users` menu item).